# Unity Event Not showing up in inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events

So I am using unity version 2018.4.36f1 and I tried calling an event in it, but it didn't appear in the inspector. Any advice on what to check, this is how I am creating the event

```
public UnityEvent <string, string> OnChatMessage;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik Unity 2018 didn't support the serialization of generics yet. See [Unity Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/Manual/script-Serialization.html)

> **Simple field types that can be serialized**
>
> - Custom non-abstract, **non-generic** classes with the Serializable attribute
> - ...

You rather need to have an explicit non-generic class like

```
[Serializable]
public ChatEvent : UnityEvent <string, string> { }
```

and then rather use

```
public ChatEvent OnChatMessage;
```

or use a newer Unity version that supports generic serialization ;)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. thanks